# How to get an array table to print every other line?

Tags: java

I have tried messing with different things and looking up but I may be using the incorrect wording. I am just wondering where the blank lines go within the indexing of arrays. Thanks for any help/guidance.

```
I'm wanting my output to look like:
Course        Hours    Score   Grade
CS121           4       98      A
// mine doesn't have this blank line
Math161         3       55      F
// or this blank line
CS124           3       66      D
```

My last print statement:`System.out.printf("%-10s %d %5d %5c\n", courses[i], credits[i], scores[i], letterGrades[i]);`

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `\n` (non-portable new-line, and singular) to `%n%n`. Like,

```
System.out.printf("%-10s %d %5d %5c%n%n", courses[i], credits[i], scores[i], 
        letterGrades[i]);
```

**or** add an empty `System.out.println();` immediately after (to add a new line).

```
System.out.printf("%-10s %d %5d %5c%n", courses[i], credits[i], scores[i], 
        letterGrades[i]);
System.out.println();
```